# Is there any program similar to Guitar pro available ?

Tags: software-recommendation

http://www.guitar-pro.com/en/index.php
The official site.

Answer (score 4):

Guitar Pro has native [Linux version](http://www.guitar-pro.com/en/index.php?pg=download). Similar open-source app is Tuxguitar. You can install it from the Software Center.

Comment: Dear Lord, how long has the native version been out?! :) I've never even heard of that!

Answer (score -1):

Wine and PlayOnLinux (Both available on the Software Center) will allow the program to run.

(I have tried GP5 but not 6...I know for a fact 5 works)